# Show speedometer like needle with mschart

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I need to create a chart looking like one shown in the image below using mschart. I can create the half circle using transparent color for the lower half of the doughnut chart, but i am unable to find way to show the needle.
[image]

The half circle is 100% and in the image the indicator is on 23%.
Also if there is another way to show the same information with mschart I can change the geography of the chart.

Comment: I am able to see image even from another system.

Comment: @amitpatel i'm having similar requirement. just want to know if you found any solution for this?

Comment: I achieved the needle using a pie chart.